# Are there any code migration method(s) if I want to change from symfony 1.4 to 3.0?

Tags: symfony1, symfony, symfony-1.4

I have a project in symfony 1.4 and want to update to symfony 3. Please, tell me the basic steps so that I can update it properly.

Comment: Maybe this [tutorial](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade) can help you? This upgrades from 2.7 to 2.8, and then to 3.0, so I don't really know if this applies for you use case. But give it a try, and then let us know if this worked. Remember to back-up your current version, just in case something doesn't go as you might expect.

Comment: Good luckk ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a tool that will make this work for you.

I'd suggest that you set up a clean Symfony3 project, see how things work there then step by step move the functionality (code) from one project to another.

I'm afraid you'll have to adapt a lot from your old project to the new one especially if your ORM there is not Doctrine2.

It would be really helpful if you have some external component tests for your project. You can run them on your new project. It will verify that new one works the same as old one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for migration from symfony 1.4 to symfony 2 or 3. 
The main problem is in source files and directories. They are different.

I'm afraid you need to rewrite whole project.
More details here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/introduction/symfony1.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no "direct" way or recipe for upgrading from Symfony 1.x to Symfony2.

If you don't want to write the whole appplication from scratch, you can do a gradual migration, wrapping your Symfony 1.x code with a Symfony2 application. The principle is simple: if the request matches a defined Symfony2 route, it will be handled by the Symfony2 application. Otherwise, it will pass to the legacy Symfony 1.x application.

There is a bundle that helps to build this architecture:

https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle

Then, you can overwrite parts of the Symfony 1 application gradually.